# Invalid initializer when using sprintf

Tags: c, date, printf

When I use the following code:

```
        ...

        time_t timer;
        struct tm* tm_info;
        char day[3];
        char month[3];
        char year[5];

        time(&timer);
        tm_info = localtime(&timer);

        strftime(day, 3, "%d", tm_info);
        strftime(month, 3, "%m", tm_info);
        strftime(year, 5, "%Y", tm_info);

char error_string_end[] = sprintf("Year: %s\n", year);

        ...
```

I get the following error:

```
my_file.c:15:27: error: invalid initializer
 15 | char string_end[] = sprintf("Year: %s\n", year);
    |                           ^~~~~~~
```

I am really ***new*** to C, I have tried `printf` directly, but the same error occurs.

What I am trying to do is, that I am trying to print the current year on to the screen first, through some variable. So, thats why I use `sprintf`.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `sprintf`, especially about what the function returns?

Comment: You should consult the documentation for `sprintf`. You're using it incorrectly.

Comment: Notably, array initializers look like `{ ... }` (and `"..."`), not function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be expecting that a string can be assigned in C. It cannot.
You also seem to be expecting that `sprintf()` returns a string. It does not.
This, and the conflict between the things that really happen, is what the compiler is trying to tell you. You cannot initialise a char array with what `sprintf()`returns.

Please read the documentation of the functions you use, e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

If you want to write a string into a `char` array, which basically is possible, you need to use it as a parameter to sprintf(), according to

```
int sprintf( char *buffer, const char *format, ... );
```

E.g.

```
int myInt=0;
myInt =sprintf( error_string_end, "Year: %s\n", year);
```

then you will find the number of printed characters in `myInt`.

For that you need of course to make sure that the target buffer is large enough.
Maybe like:

```
char error_string_end[100];
```

in the line before.

Using `snprintf()` is however a more convenient way.

Comment: Then declare/defin it or ignore the return value. I extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Better. Go to bed, sleep. Return rested tomorrow and read up on the use of sprintf(). Maybe tutorials in addition to the documentation.

Comment: Part of being a good programmer is also to know when to sleep. And it is not even one of the easier parts. My pleasure to have helped you in this unusual way. ;-) Have fun.